# Tweepy: problem with retrieving tweets attributes from Twitter API (created_at)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with Tweepy when retrieving tweets I can't get the tweet created_at date, It assigns today's date to every tweet retrieved, can I get help?

I have retrieved all other attributes I needed except for the tweet created_at attributed. It keeps on giving me today's date as the tweet extracted creation date. see the following code:

```py
query = "Australia"
max_tweets = 20

results = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                        q=query,
                        since='2018-09-8',
                        max='2018-09-21',
                        lang='en',
                        tweet_mode='extended').items(max_tweets)
for tweet in results:
    print(tweet.created_at)
```

This is what I get for the income:

```
2019-03-25 23:13:18
2019-03-25 22:56:07
2019-03-25 22:55:11
2019-03-25 22:52:00
2019-03-25 22:46:41
2019-03-25 22:45:07
2019-03-25 22:45:00
2019-03-25 22:43:33
```

I don't get the actual `created_at` date for each tweet, it gives me the date and time of the day when i run my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter only allows search for tweets within the last week. I suspect your results show the latest data available. Increase the number of tweets and you'll probably see dates going back a week at most.

Link to twitters standard API that most libraries wrap around. It specifies the standard API allows historical data searches going back a week.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview